# c# JWT using ES256, load privateKey into CngKey to be validated in talkdesk (jose-jwt)

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, cng

I am attempting to generate a JWT using a ES256 algorithm to be validated by talk desk (documentation: https://docs.talkdesk.com/docs/using-a-signed-jwt).

BUT I have an ADO.net project so I can't use any of the frameworks they sugested, so I thought the right path would be to use the https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt library.

The jose-jwt documentation state:

> ES256, ES384, ES256 ECDSA signatures requires CngKey (usually private) elliptic curve key of corresponding length. Normally existing
>   CngKey loaded via CngKey.Open(..) method from Key Storage Provider.
>   But if you want to use raw key material (x,y) and d, jose-jwt provides
>   convenient helper EccKey.New(x,y,d).

I'm having trouble understanding how does my private key that I receive from talkdesk will fit in all this.

Bellow is my code:

```
public static string Encode(TenantModel tenant)
        {

            byte [] keyBytes= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tenant.private_key); 
            var header = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "header", new { kid = tenant.key_id} }
                //{ "algorithm", tenant.key_algorithm }
            };

            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "iss", tenant.client_id },
                { "sub", tenant.client_id },
                { "aud", "https://" + tenant.account_name + ".talkdeskid.com/oauth/token" },
                { "jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
                { "exp", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300) },
                { "iat", DateTime.Now }
            };

            var privatekey = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256));
            privatekey.SignData(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.Length, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);        

            return Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, privatekey, JwsAlgorithm.ES256,header);
        }
```

I've also seen that using the CngKey.Open(..) method implies the creation of a certificate and I would like to stay away from that If possible.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue connecting to Apple's app store connect API. They hand you a .p8 file with a private key and it is not clear how to integrate this with jose-jwt which assumes you have X, Y, and D or a CngKey which is a data object I'm not very familiar with. But in the end, it wasn't very hard at all.

Open up the .p8 file in a text editor and copy out the private key. It is the character data between the "---- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ----" header and footer. Remove newlines. You have a single Base64 encoded blob of data.

```
var privateKey = "MAGTAguM[...]qaTKB2";

var key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), 
                        CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);

return Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, key, JwsAlgorithm.ES256, extraHeaders);
```